# Display image in table column if image_id equals order_id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays of objects. I would like to match order id and image item_id and display an image for order into table column.

I tried forEach over both and setState with image filename, but it only gave me one picture. Is there any other way how to accomplish this. I'm using functional based component in React.

Thanks

```js
// orders array of object
let orders = [
  {id: 1, heading: "ddd", description: "ddd", user_created: "Joe"},
  {id: 2, heading: "eee", description: "eee", user_created: "Mike"}
]

// images array of object
let images = [
  {item_id: 1, filename: "nat-2-large.jpg"},
  {item_id: 2, filename: "nat-3-large.jpg"},
]


// comparison

const [filenameForPath, setFilenameForPath] = useState('');

const getFilePath = () => {
    ordersArr.forEach(order => {
        files.forEach((file) => {
            if(order.id == file.item_id){
                console.log("success");
                setFilenameForPath(file.filename);
            }
        });
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
    getFilePath();
},[]);
```

Comment: Can you share your comparison's code? i.e. how you're comparing both array of objects

Comment: sure thing will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, at the bottom variable mapped is your result.

```
let orders = [
  {id: 1, heading: "ddd", description: "ddd", user_created: "Joe"},
  {id: 2, heading: "eee", description: "eee", user_created: "Mike"}
]

// images array of object
let images = [
  {item_id: 1, filename: "nat-2-large.jpg"},
  {item_id: 2, filename: "nat-3-large.jpg"},
]

const mapped = orders.reduce((arr, item, index)=> {
  let res;
  
 images.forEach((file) => {
   if(file.item_id === item.id) {
     res = {...item, ...file};
   }
 })
 return [...arr, res]
}, [])

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: alright thats working great but should I add this result filename values into state or how I gonna display them properly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the number of items will be equal in both and ids will be unique, you can do something like

```
   let result = orders.map((order,index) => order.id === images[index].item_id ? images[index] : null)
```